# Gitlab AutoDeploy unable to deploy K8s cluster on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am facing the deployment issues with Gitlab's AutoDevop feature. I wanted to deploy a simple NodeJs app on GKE using Gitlab's auto Deploy feature but getting the following error at line 73. I looks like the Helm chart used by AutoDeploy is missing the "Production" release:

[image]

I see the similar issue reported on [Gitlab forums](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/207978). I tried following the steps of adding CI/CD variables to disable POSTGRES.

I tried following the steps of adding the following in myproject > CI/CD Settings > Variables:

Added .gitlab/auto-deploy-values.yaml file with deploymentApiVersion: apps/v1

Added the following params
[image]

I am using `Gitlab 13.5.0-pre 390276f7bdd`

And I am using K8s on `GKE version 1.17.9-gke.6300`

I have total of 3 nodes

Am I setting the CI/CD variables correctly? Or is their anything else I am missing?

Any pointers will really be appreciated.

Comment: Could you try outside of gitlab, which releases are deployed and their statuses ('helm ls', and then 'helm status <release_name>'). Could you also try to compile YAML file out of the helm chart and apply it manually to check error message?